# On button click print on Thermal Printer using JavaScript, angular or Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, thermal-printer

I have created on NodeJS API, which I call on click of a button in angular application.

Want to print receipts of purchase on click of button, via **thermal printer**. Without any PDF save or print dialog popup, directly it should print.

I tried this nodeJS code but looks like it works for desktop application and not for web. I have UI and BE code in different codebase repo.

I tries this code:

```
'use strict';
const { PosPrinter } = require("electron-pos-printer");
class SeriesPrinter {
  constructor() { }
  printSr() {
    console.log("Inside print function");
    const print_data = [
      { type: 'text', value: 'Sample text', style: 'text-align:center;font-weight: bold' },
      { type: 'text', value: 'Another text', style: 'color: #fff' },
    ];

// returns promise<any>
PosPrinter.print(print_data, {
  printerName: 'POS-80C',
  preview: false,
  width: '170px',               //  width of content body
  margin: '0 0 0 0',            // margin of content body
  copies: 1,                   // The number of copies to print
})
  .then(() => {
    // some code ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  }
}
module.exports = SeriesPrinter;
```

**its throwing an error:**

```
Inside print function
TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor
    \node_modules\electron-pos-printer\dist\post-printer.js:87:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    \node_modules\electron-pos-p
```

Any ideas to fix this or any other solution(UI side or at nodeJS side any will work, it should print silently)

Comment: I doubt that it's possible to print without getting permission from the user, i.e. a popup of some kind.

Comment: According to [the README](https://github.com/Hubertformin/electron-pos-printer#readme) of `electron-pos-printer`, it requires electron. If you're not familiar with electron, it's a node.js framework for desktop applications that expects certain files to exist. You can see an example electron app that the README links to at https://github.com/fssonca/electron-printer. You can probably get the functionality you want by adding an API server to the example app, but it might be a little bulky.

Comment: @Steve I think you missed lined I added in CODE: 
const { PosPrinter } = require("electron-pos-printer");

I have already added it but its not working, giving error.
 TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor

Comment: @DavidKnipe its a local grocery store application, they already have default printer set and they trust site. Just want to print bills and receipts of customer purchase faster without(preview or dialogue popup).

Comment: @sandip, just by using `require("electron-pos-printer")` doesn't mean you're running your node.js application as an electron app. Rather, it's a library that expects to be run in an electron context. Your error is indicative of it not being able to get the `BrowserWindow` instance of `electron`. You can see where it's being added [here](https://github.com/Hubertformin/electron-pos-printer/blob/a98a9be2ffa6787856a684422028442d5985d906/src/post-printer.ts#L12)

Comment: Yes @Steve If I include BrowserWindow, its opening new nodeJS desktop application, I want this to print from same web application. that's the main issue I am trying to address.

Comment: Web browsers prohibit the web application to bypass print preview dialog for security reasons. As a workaround if the end user is using Chrome browser, they can utilize `--disable-print-preview` flag option with [this easy way](https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-disable-google-chrome-print-preview/). However this would disable the preview for all websites.

Comment: Build a desktop nodejs server that interfaces with the thermal printer and exposes an API on localhost that can be accessed via your webpage.

Comment: @sandip what @steve is trying to tell is correct. you are using the wrong library for this. you imported `electron-pos-printer `, which has the `electron` word in it, so it means that it's usable only by electron applications. remove `electron-pos-printer` and try other libraries like `ESCPOS` or `node-thermal-printer`. I don't think it's possible from Angular directly so you need to focus on Backend and do it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor because you're using it in a non-electron environment(browser).

What I would do since you mentioned Angular:

1. I would have a service that sends the data I want to print to a component that renders the data(actually make the visual document with the data from the server) and then window.print().

The service would look like this:

```
export class PrintService {
      isPrinting = false;
    
      constructor(private router: Router) { }
    
      printDocument(documentName: string, documentData: string[]) {
        this.isPrinting = true;
        this.router.navigate(['/',
          { outlets: {
            'print': ['print', documentName, documentData.join()]
          }}]);
      }
    
      onDataReady() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.print();
          this.isPrinting = false;
          this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { print: null }}]);
        });
      }
    }
```

and you would use it into a component like InvoiceComponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.invoiceDetails = this.invoiceIds
    .map(id => this.getInvoiceDetails(id));
  Promise.all(this.invoiceDetails)
    .then(() => this.printService.onDataReady());
}
```

2. If you don't want to do the fancy stuff, you can just keep it simple
   and lay out what you want to print and just call window.print() from
   the component:

In HTML

```
<button (click)="onPrint()">Print</button>
```

In TS

```
onPrint(){
    window.print();
}
```

3. You can also use the open/write/close popup method:

HTML

```
<div id="printSectionId" >
.......
    <button (click)="printToCart('printSectionId')" class="button">Print</button>
...
</div>
```

TS

```
export class Component{          
constructor(){}
       printToCart(printSectionId: string){
        let popupWinindow
        let innerContents = document.getElementById(printSectionId).innerHTML;
        popupWinindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=700,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
        popupWinindow.document.open();
        popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + innerContents + '</html>');
        popupWinindow.document.close();
  }

 }
```

Comment: thanks for adding sharing your ideas, in all 3 cases its opening the print popup and not auto closing it, it should silently print it, without popup.