# How to hide print dialog box in javascsript

Tags: javascript, windows, printing

I am using following code for print functionality which create the print dialog box

```
w=window.open();
w.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
w.print();
w.close();
```

But i want print functionality without dialog box.

Comment: This is not possible. (and not logical: how would you know which printer and which settings to use?)

Comment: For security reasons, well maybe not security, but annoying the hell out of web users.  Allowing a website to just print to your printer without any form of confirmation would be bad.  Saying that, I do wish that browsers had more opt in options, eg. like been able to use microphone, it would then be possible to have some for of auto-print feature built into browsers..

Comment: @CherryDT  It's logical, and browser dev's could certainly enable this.  Personally I hate how browser's are deliberately held back, and we all know why?,  Make the browser more capable and the App store gravy train get's effected.  Proof in point is how Safari IOS is the worst for this.

Comment: Printing in any OS is a process that's quite complicated, different per platform and full of pitfalls. You can have printers with uncommon formats like receipt printers, you can have multiple printers with the same name, you need  a way to add a printer, you need a preview, you need to know whether certain features like duplex printing are supported by a printer or not before offering it, printers have custom options you can open in a driver-provided dialog box, etc etc - even some desktop apps implement printing poorly, it would be detrimental for UX to let every website try to do it...

Comment: (The level of access required to _properly_ implement printing also opens an unwanted vulnerability surface because then websites could exploit bugs in printer drivers more directly.)

Comment: @CherryDT  I auto print to printers all the time, without that feature I'm pretty sure my customers would be well miffed.  It's really not that complicated.  You can defend browser reasons for not enabling features, that's up to you.  But personally I find doing this is defending a practise that's stopping Web App's been 1st class apps..  Shame really!!..

Comment: It's a different situation in things like a PoS app that runs in Electron, people already trust it enough to install it on their machine and it is configured and tested once to work properly with a given printer. But just generally adding this support to websites sounds not great to me because then even some websites that don't need it would want to use it because the boss thought it's cool, and it would cause UX issues because they didn't cover all the scenarios. I would prefer an option to "allow automatic printing with current settings" in the print dialog so we can have the best of both.

Comment: @CherryDT  How is there a bigger security or technical reasons,.  You can already print now!, you press the print dialog button, so in some respect's all that's been asked is the ability for that button to not be pressed, the extra vulnerability is really minor.  Yes, dev's would not want to be sloppy in implementing a feature, but remember I'm also saying it's a opt in feature, like microphone access.  etc.  IOW: I'm saying it would be great if Web App's became 1st class App's like from the App store, it's better for everyone apart from the App Store gravy train..

Comment: @CherryDT I also ran into similar issue, tried to use electron but its opening another desktop app, which is not there requirement. Details of my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751832/on-button-click-print-on-thermal-printer-using-javascript-angular-or-node-js